# Build Angular2 - Typescript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, build, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run an application on Visual Studio Code by using this command: 
"npm start"

but I am receiving this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\Desktop\angular-tour-of-heroes\npm-debug.log
```

I did these steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
2. cd quickstart
3. npm install
4. npm start

and it fails on step 4. 
how can I fix that?

Comment: use `ng serve` make sure that you have installed the angular cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the version of Node.
I install it from this link: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
and then I did:

> npm install
>
> npm start

and the server ran.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **build new Angular 2 app**, my advice is to use [**Angular Cli**](https://cli.angular.io/) instead of **quickstart**.

After installing Angular Cli, creating & starting the app is simple in 3 steps:

```
ng new my-app 
cd my-app
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your version of Node and NPM.

From the link below:

**Verify that you are running at least node v4.x.x and npm 3.x.x** by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. **Older versions produce errors.**

[Quickstart Prerequisites](https://github.com/angular/quickstart#prerequisites)

These are the versions you are currently running, according to the output from your console.

```
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
```